# How bad is slack \makeatother discipline really?

Tags: macros, best-practices, catcodes

Following [Will Robertson's admission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999810/latex-extract-substring-ignore-characters/2003807#2003807) that *Fwiw, i'm not aware of any troubles with a missing* `\makeatother`, *but you're right. It's a bad habit of mine to omit it*, and my own progressive slackness about the same thing following my realisation that I never see it matter, I wonder how important the `\makeatother` discipline is?

The worst consequence I can think of for experienced users from slackness about closing with `\makeatother` is that one's slackness might spread to omitting `\ExplSyntaxOff` with `expl3`, which is very far from trouble-free.  But that's not a mistake anyone is going to get used to making.

The insidious worry is that not following the discipline means that some people might become unclear about the distinction between "package/Knuth namespace" and "user namespace".

But I can't say that either of these considerations seems very urgent.  It doesn't seem important in the same way as such a programmatic discipline as eliminating avoidable state in interfaces.  Is there something more compelling?

Comment: You soon know when you forget `\ExplSyntaxOff`!

Comment: Heh, I guess I shouldn't have admitted that!

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73851/can-the-makeatletter-makeatother-mechanics-lead-to-parsing-problems#comment157926_73856) is a comment about this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In theory it would be possible that there is a `@` direct after a macro in the users document or in one of the auxiliary files. Without the `\makeatother` this would cause trouble.

A second source of trouble are special packages which read user input and compare them using `\let`/`\futurelet` and `\ifx`. I'm not sure how the `array` package parses a potential `@` in the column definition of `tabular`, but e.g. my `tikz-timing` package allows `@{<code>}` sequences and I was wise enough to test for `@` with catcode *letter* and *other*. If I wouldn't have thought of that a missing `\makeatother` would break certain user code without much idea why.

In general it is good programming practice to close everything you open explicitly by yourself. This can be `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` or `\openout`/`\closeout` or anything like it. This doesn't apply when the change was localized using a group.

Comment: Good answer. There are some small packages around that don't check for the catcode of @ so you're absolutely right.

Comment: I'm convinced.  Incidentally, the question arose from [this edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/11735/revisions).

Answer (score 16):

A problem with slack `\makeatother` discipline is that it clashes with the use of `\@` to reset the space factor after non-sentence-ending periods.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Articles from the Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.

Articles from the Proc.\@ Amer.\@ Math.\@ Soc.

\makeatletter
Articles from the Proc.\@ Amer.\@ Math.\@ Soc.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, this seems so because TeX doesn't remove spaces after the special single *character* macros. AFAIK it doesn't have to because it doesn't have to look ahead for the rest of the macro name because it is by definition only one character long. If the `@` is a letter more letter could follow and the space is removed like after every normal macro.

Comment: Thanks for providing the explanation. I was in a bit of a rush, so I hadn't.

Comment: This is an excellent point.  It's also one that could easily be overlooked when proofing copy.