# Is it really bad to use \makeatletter and \makeatother in a package or class file?

Tags: package-writing, latex-base

In my answer to this question [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/2693) I  apparently wrote:

> The commands should not be used within `.sty` and `.cls` files themselves as they may conflict with the catcode changes that occurs when package and class files are loaded.

In fact this particular line was added in by Will Robertson.  So I'm curious: can someone come up with a concrete example of how having `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` at the beginning and end of a package or class would affect another package?

I'm not talking about what happens if you leave one of them out, as discussed here:

[How bad is slack \makeatother discipline really?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11750/2693)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

First of all, `\makeatletter` is unnecessary in `.sty` or `.cls` files, as the default catcode regime includes it; this is presumably to encourage package writers to hide their macros using `@`-laden names.  For this reason, I believe that using *this* command is harmless in package files.

However, using the *pair* of commands together is harmful, because unlike in a document, you do *not* want to return to the `@ = other` setup within the package.  These are document commands and the standard ordering `\makeatletter \makeatother` assumes that `\makeatother` is actually undoing the previous change, whereas in packages, it is the one making the change.

**Edit:** Here is a more informed answer.  According to `source2e.pdf`, the following scheme is used to load packages and classes:

1. First, the options and such are gathered.
2. Then the name of the current file (i.e. `mypackage.sty`), *along with the catcode of `@`*, are saved on a stack.
3. Then `\makeatletter` is run and, if appropriate, the requested file is loaded.
4. Afterwards, the stack is popped and the pre-package-load state restored.

In other words, the following ignorant code has *no effect at all*:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bad}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

bad.sty:

```latex
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\RequirePackage{unsuspecting}
```

However, it is quite possible that a package does *not* use `\RequirePackage`, but just `\input`.  In that case, the catcode is *not* protected and indeed, errors can arise, as you can check yourself by making `bad.sty`, for example:

```
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\input{pgfkeys.sty}
```

If that seems artificial, have a look at `pgfkeys.sty` itself: it `\input`s `pgfkeys.code.tex`, and that file, in turn, `\input`s `pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex`.  Presumably, the author felt himself safe once within his own package, but did not suspect that someone else might circumvent the package-loading protection mechanisms also!

Answer (score 35):

This was a lot more serious in LaTeX2.09 as there LaTeX just executed `\makeatletter` *once* before handling all the `.sty` files (LaTeX2.09 didn't gave the `.cls`/`.sty` distinction). So it was a common problem, almost a FAQ, that packages were released that executed `\makeatother` at the end of the file and they worked in isolation but broke any following "style files" (aka packages).

So one of the first things done for 2e was to reset the catcode of `@` on loading each package, maintaining a stack so that the catcode is restored at the end of the package to what it was before.  Thus *by design* it is hard to find an example where a rogue `\makeatother` at the end of a package does harm.

That said, it's better practice not to fall than to rely on a safety net.

Answer (score 25):

As long as you're aware not to do bad things inside your own package (like Ryan Reich's example), you seem to be safe within the bounds of what LaTeX offers.

But still dangers lurk around the corner.

If I say

```
\usepackage{afterpackage}

\AfterPackage{foo}{\input{bar}}

\usepackage{foo}
```

and inside `foo.sty`

```
\makeatother
```

and inside `bar.tex`

```
\protected@edef\baz{quux}
```

then I get an error because `@` is not a letter (which doesn't happen without the `\makeatother`).

(the main point of this answer is of course that the (unsuspecting) person using `\AfterPackage` is not neccessarily the same as the package author)

Comment: So the real moral is "don't `\input` files when you mean to `\usepackage` them".

Comment: @RyanReich There's no reason why `bar.tex` should be a package. It could be an `aux` file, `toc`, `out` or anything. There's no reason to assume the use of `\AfterPackage` wouldn't work, so leaving `@` as other at the end of a package is clearly an error.

Comment: You're right.  I guess this shows the importance of knowing *why* the default catcode regime in packages is what it is; i.e. how it happens.  It happens at each package load.