# Problem with musixtex's mezzo piano dynamic

Tags: packages

I am trying to use dynamics marks on my text by using the `musixtex` package. It works well except for the mezzo piano mark (\mp), which is not recognized. According to the manual (section 2.17.5) my code is correct (http://icking-music-archive.org/software/musixtex/musixdoc.pdf). Can someone spot what is wrong here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\begin{document}
\pppp, \ppp, \pp, \p, \mf, \f, \ff, \fff, \ffff, \sF % all these work fine
\mp % but this doesn't
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\mp` is actually a command defined by `\LaTeX` itself and it can only be used in maths mode (where it yields `∓`), that's why you get an error. To overwrite the command, just add `\let\mp\mezzopiano` after `\usepackage{musixtex}`.

*Be aware, that in doing so you overwrite a `LaTeX` command, that other packages may or may not heavily rely on - or at least expect to work in a certain way.*

You could also just use the longer name `\mezzopiano` if you do not want to overwrite `\mp`.

---

As `\mp` is a `LaTeX` macro, the package is wary of overwriting it. While all the other commands are defined as you would expect, e.g. *mezzo-forte*: `\def\mf{{\ppff m\p@kern\f@kern f}}` in `musixtex.tex`, *mezzo-piano* is defined as: `\def\mp@{{\ppff m\p@kern p}}` (note the `@`); just after that, the longer command `\mezzopiano` is defined: `\let\mezzopiano\mp@`.

Similarly, the macro for *sforzando* is not called `\sf` but `\sF` to avoid clashes with important `LaTeX` macros (`\sf` switches to sans serif font).
Following that example, you could use `\let\mP\mezzopiano` instead of `\let\mp\mezzopiano`, so you do not overwrite standard commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\let\mp\mezzopiano
\begin{document}
\pppp, \ppp, \pp, \p, \mf, \f, \ff, \fff, \ffff, \sF
\mp
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the extra `@` does in the definition of `\mf`, possibly?

Comment: The `@` makes sure `\mp@` is not `\mp`, so the latter is not automatically overwritten - as `\def` would normally do. Macros that are (normally) not supposed to be accessed by the user on a document level often contain an `@` [read more about that here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6240/). That is why the package provides the longer macro `\mezzopiano`.

Comment: Ah — so it’s in a `\makeatletter` section, and the `@` is part of the name of the command.  Got it, thanks!

Comment: Yep somewhat, it is within a `.sty` file and thus [automatically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62586/35864) in a `\makeatletter` section.