# Proof redefinition not working

Tags: environments, preamble, proof-package

My proof redefinition command does not work on some cases and I cannot see the pattern nor the reason. These are the more reduced MN(N)E I could get. They were reproduced on Overleaf.

MWE 1:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
I'm a froop
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

MNWE 1:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\leavevmode\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\mbox{}\par\nobreak\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
I'm a froop
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

That would seem to indicate that my redefinition is not working. However, by adding the preamble in a separate file things seem to work fine.

The following is the main file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Preamble}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
I'm a froop
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

MWE 2 (Preamble):

```
\ProvidesPackage{Preamble}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\leavevmode\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\mbox{}\par\nobreak\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}

\makeatletter
\makeatother
```

MNEW 2 (Preamble):

```
\ProvidesPackage{Preamble}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\makeatletter
\makeatother

\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\leavevmode\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\mbox{}\par\nobreak\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
```

The point of knowing what's happening is to know where I can or cannot place my redefinition on the preamble.

Comment: You need `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` *around* the `\renewenvironment` (that is to say `\makeatletter` needs to go before the entire redefinition block and `\makeatother` after the block, putting the two commands directly after each other has basically no effect). If you put the redefinition into a `.sty` file that you then load with `\usepackage` the `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` is implicit. (Generally `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` should be avoided when writing `.sty` files.)

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/35864

Comment: The ```\makeatletter ... \makeatother``` intended to represent another definition, that's why there where outside. I now understand (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62583/is-it-really-bad-to-use-makeatletter-and-makeatother-in-a-package-or-class-fil) the problem is that I shouldn't use the ```\makeatother``` command on ```.sty``` files (and if I do I should re-start it for other definitions and packages with ```\makeatletter```). Is that correct? Thank you for your comment and the reference.

Comment: Yes. In general you should not use `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` in `.sty` files and in MNEW 2 the `\makeatother` is exactly the problem. A related issue is discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62583/35864. In your examples there is absolutely no reason for `\makeatletter` or `\makeatother` in the `.sty` file, so you can just drop them.