# Can the makeatletter/makeatother mechanics lead to parsing problems?

Tags: macros, catcodes

The reason for using `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` has been discussed in many places, for instance [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do).

However I think that this trick of playing around with the "@" character is itself quite a hack. Couldn't the temporary redefinition of @'s catcode lead to problems? This might not be the practically most commonly occurring usage scenario, but if a section of code embraced by `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` uses a macro `\somemacro` and we are used to applying this macro to certain arguments without braces, as in `\somemacro@`, couldn't this break code? Also, considering this possibility, is there a non-contrived use case in which such breakage might occur?

(Yep, this is a question that likely belongs into the domain "theory", but familiarity with parsing matters and compilation gives me a desire to see this discussed/documented.)

Comment: I like this question.  However, the only case this problem has bitten me was during debugging, when I forgot to say `\makeatletter`.  But I'd love to hear what really experienced TeX users/programmers have to say.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11750/how-bad-is-slack-makeatother-discipline-really

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you want to *directly* use a macro with an `@` in its name (at-macro, from now on), then you have to make sure that `@` is considered a letter, that is the call must be after a `\makeatletter` declaration.

However normal macros that are defined in terms of at-macros don't need to be used in such a regime. Let's look at an example.

The LaTeX kernel defines `\item` as follows:

```
\def\item{%
  \@inmatherr\item
  \@ifnextchar [ {\@item}{\@noitemargtrue \@item[\@itemlabel]}%
}
```

and it does so where `\makeatletter` is in force. When the `\def` is executed, TeX stores `\item` and its replacement text in memory, but in a form that is independent of the actual characters that form the names of the used control sequences. Thus, when `\item` appears in your document (where `\makeatother` is usually in force), the fact that its expansion contains at-macros is irrelevant as far as the expansion process is concerned: TeX retrieves from its memory the meaning of `\item` in the internal form and the same happens when the first control sequence, `\@inmatherr`, must be expanded.

To the contrary, if you need to modify the definition of `\item` in order to add something at the beginning, this has to be made properly:

```
\makeatletter
\def\item{%
  \typeout{Doh! An item!}%
  \@inmatherr\item
  \@ifnextchar [ {\@item}{\@noitemargtrue \@item[\@itemlabel]}%
}
\makeatother
```

since you are referring to at-macros in the body of the definition. Without `\makeatletter`, the line `\@inmatherr\item` would be parsed (I use • to separate one token from another)

```
\@•i•n•m•a•t•h•e•r•r•\item
```

that is, eleven tokens and not two! This is because in normal regime `@` is not a letter: when TeX is looking for a command name because it has found a backslash, any non-letter immediately stops the scanning and the command name will be formed by *that* non-letter.

What's a letter? Any character with category code 11 *at the moment the scanning takes place*. But, I repeat, once the scanning has been performed, the control sequence enters TeX in an internal format that's independent of category codes.

Looking at your example with `\somemacro@`, it's "easy" to distinguish the two cases:

```
\makeatletter
\somemacro@ % <- ONE token
\makeatother
\somemacro@ % <- TWO tokens
```

So, if you have defined both `\somemacro@` (as an at-macro) and `\somemacro`, in a normal place of the document the combination `\somemacro@` will expand `\somemacro` and not the at-macro. In fact, the scanning for a control sequence name will be stopped by `@`, which is not a letter in the document (if you haven't done `\makeatletter`, of course).

A doubt can arise for the following:

```
\makeatletter
\def\somemacro@#1{Do something smart with #1}
\def\somemacro#1{\somemacro@{(#1)}}
\makeatother
```

and the input (under normal conditions, that is, `\makeatother`)

```
\somemacro@
```

Now these are *two* tokens: `\somemacro•@`, so `@` will be the argument to `\somemacro` and the final result would be printing

> Do something smart with (@)

It takes a while to digest these tricks; but once one realizes that TeX works with the tokens it forms by reading the input file and works on them after translating into an internal format (which is irrelevant for the user to know), things begin to go more smoothly.

Comment: Great! Now let's say that `\somemacro` is defined elsewhere (and let's leave the question open whether you also define `\somemacro@` in the "makeat"-block). If I say want to print something containing the letter "@" in that block, the original `\somemacro`-command won't be found, right? And if this is so, is my understanding correct that this can only be an issue with direct "@"-letters in the input? (That is, that's the only case I need to in theory worry about.)

Comment: @user14996 No, in a `\makeatother` context, `\somemacro@` are two tokens that will *never* be interpreted as the macro with name "somemacro@", be it defined or not.

Comment: Yes, but what I meant is that in a `\makeatletter` context, the string `\somemacro@` will *always* be interpreted as a single token, and thus if I'm used to writing `\somemacroSOMETOKEN` (because I want to use the macro `\somemacro`, not a macro `\somemacro@`) instead of the parenthesized `\somemacro{SOMETOKEN}`, I'm in trouble, correct? Thus I'm wondering about the range of practical cases where this can lead to trouble and if supplying the single-token argument `@` is really the only case. If so, it's valuable to have it be stated somewhere (like on this forum).

Comment: @user14996 In the "programming environment" (where `\makeatletter` is in force, essentially) one must be quite careful; a final `@` in a macro name may be a problem, but there are many other small quirks that experience will help in avoiding.

Comment: To rephrase my point: the class of problem cases I had in mind is "whenever I supply a single `@`-argument without curly braces to an `@`-less macro name, I need to be aware that things are parsed as one token in the 'programming environment', not the intended two". That's all my question was about. And supplying curly braces already fixes that, if I'm right. Anyways, I think we're in agreement.