# Why doesn't \makeatletter work inside \newcommand?

Tags: macros

After hours of banging my brain against my skull, I narrowed down an issue I'm having to the fact that `\makeatletter` doesn't work inside `\newcommand`. Commands that I call after `\makeatletter` are registered as undefined, as if `\makeatletter` didn't do anything.

Why is this the case?

In the example below, I define two commands. Calling one of them from the document body causes the undefined error, while the other doesn't.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}

\newcommand{\commandThatFails}{
    \makeatletter \comma@parse{}{} \makeatother
}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\commandThatWorks}{
        \comma@parse{}{}
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hi there.

\commandThatFails
\commandThatWorks

\end{document}
```

Comment: Because you can't change the catcode of @ inside the body of the document. The second version is the correct one since it allows you to include control sequences with @ character and doesn't cause any problem upon execution. The first one is trying to change the catcode upon execution and failing.

Comment: @percusse I'm not sure that's the correct explanation… I mean, it partially is, but it's a bit of a mess.

Comment: @Manuel I'm always up for a good schooling :)

Comment: @percusse I know why that happens but I'm not sure I know how to explain it in english without writing a whole paragrph. The thing is that tokens are stored when the macro is defined, in the second one you store `\comma@parse`, but in the first one, since `\makeatletter` is only saved (not executed) the following that is saved are the tokens `\comma`, `@`, `p`, `a`, `r`, `s`, `e`.

Comment: this must be a duplicate, but it's the same reason you can't use `\verb` in a command argument. catcodes change the tokenisation of _characters_ they do not affect tokens tat have already been parsed. when the argument to `\newcommand is scanned` you get token `\makeatletter` token `\comma` token `@` token `p` token `a` token `r` token `s` token `e` when the command is executed the catcode of `@` is changed but that has no affect on tokens

Comment: @Manuel Oh in that sense. Yes I meant as a cs parsing. My bad you are right, wrong wording.

Comment: @percusse you can change the catcode at any point in the document or in the preamble, but catcodes don't affect tokens.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Right, sloppy on my part.

Comment: @Manuel I leave the floor to you since I deserve to be punished :) Can you also add that `\csname comma@parse \endcsname` doesn't require cat change?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73851/can-the-makeatletter-makeatother-mechanics-lead-to-parsing-problems

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When `\makeatletter` is executed, it changes the
[catcode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16412/94878) of `@` to 11 (letter) so it can be
part of a macro name. However, when defining a macro or using an argument of a
macro, the tokens are stored without being executed.

So here,

```
\newcommand{\commandThatFails}{
    \makeatletter \comma@parse{}{} \makeatother
}
```

`\makeatletter` is stored as a token in the command rather than being executed.
Because `@` is still a non-letter, the command parses as the tokens `\comma`,
`@`, `p`, `a`, `r`, `s`, and `e`, which is *not* `\comma@parse`

However, in your second example, `\makeatletter` is executed *before* the
command is defined, so that `\comma@parse{}{}` is parsed correctly:

```
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\commandThatWorks}{
        \comma@parse{}{}
    }
\makeatother
```

This is for the same reason that [`\verb|...|` fails within
arguments:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24578/94878) it’s not executed, just
stored, causing any strange characters to cause all sorts of errors.

As noted by @percusse, in this cases where you need `@`-macros just once or
twice, you can use `\csname comma@parse\endcsname` which expands all the macros
and then converts every token between `\csname` and `\endcsname` to a macro
name. So this would also work:

```
\newcommand{\commandThatDoesntFail}{\csname comma@parse\endcsname{}{}}
```

Where the command resolves to `\comma@parse{}{}` (note that the tailing `{}{}`
is treated as arguments to `\comma@parse`, not `\endcsname`).

Further reading:

- [What catcodes are within LaTeX.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16412/94878)
- [More on `\csname ... \endcsname`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39382/94878)
- [A similar problem related to changing catcodes within a command definition.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152469/94878)

Comment: +1 (I've written answers with much worse English than that, and I am English:-)