# \@percentchar in \newcommand function

Tags: shell-escape

I moved a part of my code to function and that stopped working. I don't understand why?

this code is working:

```
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{start cmd echo /k magick convert _SDC4828.jpg  -crop 50\@percentchar x100\@percentchar\space +repage _SDC4828.jpg}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

This not working:

```
\newcommandx{\twosidepic}{
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{start cmd echo /k magick convert _SDC4828.jpg  -crop 50\@percentchar x100\@percentchar\space +repage _SDC4828.jpg}
\makeatother
}

\begin{document}
\twosidepic
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` must be used outside of `\newcommand`.

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201348/35864

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.