# \@abspage@last fails to typeset number in header

Tags: header-footer, tex-core, fancyhdr

I tried to typeset the total pages number in right header by  `\@abspage@last` under pagestyle `fancy`. Instead of number, the text `abspage@last` is printed. Why? And how to deal with it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Page \thepage\ of \makeatletter\@abspage@last\makeatother}
\begin{document}
First page:\\
total pages are: \@abspage@last\\ % typeset abspage@last. Why not give error message?
total pages are: \makeatletter\@abspage@last\makeatother % typeset the right number
\clearpage
Second page
\clearpage
Third page
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. Looks like you don't understand how makeatletter and catcode works. It's a long topic...

Comment: 2. LaTeX is built on top of TeX, its capability to give error messages is limited (besides, that's a totally valid thing you can typeset in LaTeX)

Comment: See [macros - Why doesn't \makeatletter work inside \newcommand? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201348/why-doesnt-makeatletter-work-inside-newcommand) for a possible explanation

Comment: use `\makeatletter\rhead{Page \thepage\ of \@abspage@last}\makeatother`. You must change the catcode before the @ is seen by TeX.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer As for `\rhead{Page \thepage\ of \makeatletter\@abspage@last\makeatother}`, why does`\makeatletter` not change the catcode before the @ is seen by TeX?

Comment: TeX sees it when you *define* the \rhead in the preamble, not when it is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\makeatletter` *around* `\rhead{...}`, not inside it, but you can do better.

There is no “official” interface for using `\@abspage@last` in the document, mainly because it's not meant to save the last page number, but the total number of pages, including those with different numbering scheme.

If you don't change numbering scheme, you can use it by first defining your own interface

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lastpagenumber}{\@abspage@last}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Page \thepage\ of \lastpagenumber}

\begin{document}

First page:
\clearpage
Second page
\clearpage
Third page

\end{document}
```

The default value is 1073741823, which you will obtain when the `.aux` file doesn't yet exist.

If you want to be warned that a rerun is necessary, you can check whether `\@abspage@last` equals `\maxdimen`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lastpagenumber}{%
  \ifnum\@abspage@last=\maxdimen
    \@lastpagewarning
  \else
    \@abspage@last
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\@lastpagewarning}{%
   \@latex@warning@no@line{Could not determine last page number, rerun LaTeX}%
   ??\gdef\@lastpagewarning{??}%
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Page \thepage\ of \lastpagenumber}

\begin{document}

First page:
\clearpage
Second page
\clearpage
Third page

\end{document}
```

If the `.aux` file is missing or, for some reason, `\@abspage@last` isn't yet defined, you will get

```
LaTeX Warning: Could not determine last page number, rerun LaTeX.
```

Of course this would fail if your document has 1073741823 pages, but…

Comment: Why does dirct use of `\@abspage@last` just gobble `\@` and typeset `abspage@last`?

Comment: @lyl Because the text stored has `@` of category code 12, so TeX just executes `\@` and prints `abspage@last`. That's why you should use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` ***around*** `\rhead{...}`, not ***inside*** it, where it has no useful effect. Another possibility is to do `\csname @abspage@last\endcsname` inside `\rhead`; you can remove `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` that do nothing.

Comment: ` \@` typeset nothing and does not give any error message, so in TeX, what does \@ mean?

Comment: @lyl You can use it after a period following an abbreviation, which should not be sentence ending (but in this case `.~` is more frequent; or before a period to tell TeX to consider it as a sentence ending period, when it follows a capital letter.

Comment: Thank you so much! I lean a lot from this question.

Comment: quote: `The default value is 1073741823, which you will obtain when the .aux file doesn't yet exist.` How to make sure .aux file does exist when I use `\@abspage@last`? I don't want `1073741823`, the number of total pages is I desire.

Comment: @lyl You just compile again.

Comment: But each time the first try fails to complete comilation and causes error. For example, `\makeatletter\foreach \i in {1,...,\@abspage@last} {(\i)}\makeatother`

Comment: @lyl The code in my answer doesn't produce errors when the `.aux` file doesn't exist. If yours does, then the changes you made are the cause.

Comment: For example, the document only contain this: `\makeatletter\foreach \i in {1,...,\@abspage@last} {(\i)}\makeatother` . The first running causes `ERROR: Dimension too large.` I think this is because no `.aux` file exists as you mentioned.

Comment: @lyl That's obvious. You can add `\def\@abspage@last{-1}` in the code, after `\@lastpagewarning`

Comment: Would you kindly provide more details about why dircet use of \@abspage@last in the above sample is wrong? And why does `\def\@abspage@last{-1}` solve the problem?