# Issue with \scalebox, \makeatletter, and \input

Tags: graphics, input

A colleague of mine had a LaTeX-specific issue for which I did not exactly know the cause of the issue. I have distilled a Minimal Working Example to illustrate the issue.

Originally my colleague had several files and used `\include` in the following way:

Main .tex file: testi.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\test@}{test}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\scalebox{0.8}{
    \input{testii}
}

\end{document}
```

Included .tex file: testii.tex:

```
\makeatletter
    \test@
\makeatother
```

This worked without any problems (the included constructs of this form originated from automated generated code to annotate .pdf images). Then, my colleague tried to make a single *.tex file. Hence, he replaced the `\input` command by including the content of testii.tex in testi.tex:

Single-file testi.tex: testd.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\test@}{test}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\scalebox{0.8}{
    \makeatletter
        \test@
    \makeatother
}

\end{document}
```

The file testd.tex did, however, not compile: the error message was:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
 <argument>  \makeatletter \test
```

Hence: LaTeX reads the command `\test` instead of `\test@`, which should have been read due to the `\makeatletter` construct. We found a way to resolve the issue (by placing `\scalebox` inside a `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` pair), but still I am wondering what the cause (bug?) of the differences in behavior between inlined LaTeX code and `\input`-ed LaTeX code is.

Answer (score 2):

This is unrelated to `\input` (or to the specifics of `\scalebox`)

in

```
\scalebox{0.8}{
    \makeatletter
        \test@
    \makeatother
}
```

the argument has already been parsed and tokenised as `\test` `@` *before* it is executed, so `\makeatletter` has no effect. This is the same reason that you can not use `\verb` in the argument to another command. You need

```
    \makeatletter
\scalebox{0.8}{%< don't forget this
        \test@
}
    \makeatother
```

Comment: I'm facing this issue with [latexpand](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexpand) (I'm the author). When expanding `\scalebox{}{ \input{figure.pdf_t} }` I can't find a clean way to put a `\makeatletter` at the right place automatically. Your solution works well when writing the code manually though, and thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @MatthieuMoy 99.999% of the time you can just put a single `\makeatletter` in the preamble and forget about the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I used to have a more brute-force approach to \makeatletter but I got complains from a user referencing 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11750/how-bad-is-slack-makeatother-discipline-really For now, I documented the bug and workaround in latexpand --help.